# Не рисуется треугольник, OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Не рисуется треугольник, но могу понять почему. Если я делаю всё в одном файле, в функции main, то рисуется, если выношу всю логику в класс, то не рисуется. В чем может быть проблема? Код ошибок не выдает.

```
    Triangle::Triangle()
{
    this->verticies[0] = vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0);
    this->verticies[1] = vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0);
    this->verticies[2] = vec3(-0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0);

    this->vertexShader.readShader("Shaders/Triangle/vertexShader.vert");
    this->fragmentShader.readShader("Shaders/Triangle/colorShader");

    this->vertexShader.createShader();
    this->fragmentShader.createShader();

    this->shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(this->shaderProgram, this->vertexShader.shader);
    glAttachShader(this->shaderProgram, this->fragmentShader.shader);
    glLinkProgram(this->shaderProgram);

    GLint success;
    GLchar info[512];

    glGetProgramiv(this->shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        log("ERROR::LINK_PROGRAMM");
        glGetProgramInfoLog(this->shaderProgram, 512, nullptr, info);
        cout << success;
    }

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(this->verticies), this->verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Triangle::draw(GLFWwindow& window)
{
    glUseProgram(this->shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glfwSwapBuffers(&window);
}
```

Comment: а где вызывается draw?

Comment: В игровом цикле, я немного переделал, вроде заработало.

Comment: Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы до публикации вопроса.